Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\YOURNAME\....firebase_core-3.6.0\android\build.gradle' from cache
Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-3.6.0\android\build.gradle' from cache.

flutter doctor (fine) [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-US) [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher) [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0) [√] Chrome - develop for the web [√] Android Studio (version 2024.2) [√] VS Code (version 1.94.2) [√] Connected device (3 available) [√] Network resources
`new Pc Flutter setup getting this error only on android
working and running find on fluttre web, IOS, only not working on android
latest flutter sdk(3.24.3), latest android studio
before firebase setup project working fine on every device android, ios, web
after firebase setup getting this error
using FlutterFire CLI. for setup firebase`
